# I am trying to get all the audio files from my internal and external storage

Tags: java

I use media Store to get All the files from the Storage but my code didn't work . help me to solve issue. I tried all the tricks from the internet but also after that i am not able to solve this..

```
enter code here
   public List<Song> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
                final ArrayList<Song> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<Song>();
                File temp= (File)Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String selection=MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                Log.d("file",temp.toString());
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    //    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                       // MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST
                       // MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
                };
        
                Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection, selection,null,null,null);
        
                if (c != null) {
                    do {
                        Song audioModel = new Song();
                        int path =(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                        int  name =c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                        int album =(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        audioModel.setaName(c.getString(name));
                        Log.e("Uri",(c.getString(name)));
                        audioModel.setaAlbum(c.getString(album));
                        audioModel.setaPath(c.getString((path)));
                        Log.e("Name :",  audioModel.toString());
        
                        tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
        
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                    c.close();
                }
                Log.e("N",  Integer.toString(tempAudioList.size()) );
                return tempAudioList; }
```

Comment: `but my code didn't work` - what exactly didn't work? what are you expecting to happen? what actually happened?

Comment: I tried to print all the song name but it returns noting  by using   Log.e("Name :",  audioModel.toString()); . I am excepting it will print all the song name in my Log cat console